# JavaScript - AngularJS HTML interpreter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array with content and HTML tags like:

```
    for (car in cars.parking[0]){
         content.push('<br />');
         for (token in cars.parking[0].now) {
              content.push("text");
              contentString = content.join("");
         }
     }
```

But I my html, when I do:

```
 My Content : {{myContent}}
```

It displays:

```
text text text text text  <br /> text text text
```

**I expect**, like in my console:

```
text text text text text
text text text
```

How can I fixe that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `ng-bing-html` directive if you want to add html in to view like below

```
<p ng-bind-html="myContent"></p>
```

and also you need to add `angular-sanitize.js` and define the dependency as `angular.module('yourModule', ['ngSanitize'])` inorder to work this

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. I added "angular-sanitize.js" also angular.module('yourModule', ['ngSanitize']) but it breaks everything.

Comment: did u replace `yourModule` with your module name ?

Comment: Normally I  have angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope, $http, Pages) { and with angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']).controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope, $http, Pages) { it doesn't work.